# Implementing Secret Sharing Among Multiple Parties

Tags: algorithm-design, provable-security, secret-sharing, information-theory

I'm working on a scenario where a safe has a lock code '42', and this code needs to be shared securely among four individuals. The goal is to set up a system where at least two out of these four individuals must combine their individual pieces of information to recover the original code and open the safe. However, no single individual should be able to access the code on their own.

I'm looking for a cryptographic method or algorithm that allows this kind of secret sharing, where a secret can be divided and then reconstructed only with the collaboration of at least a certain number of participants. How can this be implemented effectively? Are there existing algorithms or techniques in cryptography that can be applied to this situation?

Comment: You managed to tag your question with "secret-sharing" and mention "secret sharing" several times. It seems to me that "secret sharing" is also the answer to what you have written, so perhaps you could clarify why it is not.